# void(^)(NSData*) what does it mean?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios5

Hi I am using this [library](https://github.com/norsez/BDMultiDownloader/tree/master/Classes) and I found the function:

```
- (void) queueRequest:(NSString*)urlPath completion:(void(^)(NSData*))completionWithDownloadedData;
```

I try to pass a simple `NSData *data;` and it throw an error, what really mean `(void(^)(NSData*))`? Is the first time that I see it.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`(void(^)(NSData*))` declares a code block.
You can call your function this way.

```
[obj queueRequest:urlPath completion:^(NSData* data){
            /* some code */
        }];
```

`data` is a parameter to your block, which you can work with. The block will be called when the queueRequest will finish, asynchronously.

Answer (score 4):

The interface is asynchronous, meaning that the data will only be available sometime later. This means that the method can’t simply return the `NSData*` (without blocking for all the time, which is impractical). The problem is nowadays often solved with [blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html), and the completion argument here is a block that takes an `NSData*` argument and returns `void`. This is how you call such a method:

```
[foo queueRequest:path completion:^(NSData *receivedData) {
    NSLog(@"Received data: %@", receivedData);
}];
```

The call will return immediately and the block will be executed sometime later, when the data is available.

Answer (score 1):

It's a block that accepts a `NSData` object as it's only argument and returns nothing.

See Apple's [Blocks Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html).